# не работает setWhen для Notification

Tags: android, уведомления

Я получаю текущее время в миллисекундах и добавляю к нему еще 60000(1 минута), но уведомление приходит не через минуту, а сразу.

**Код:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101;
private static String CHANNEL_ID = "test channel";
private EditText editText;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createNotificationChanel();

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String textForNotification = editText.getText().toString();

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                            .setContentText(textForNotification)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());
        }
    });
}

private void createNotificationChanel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID, "Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Some description");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setWhen()` не устанавливает время для показа уведомления, но устанавливает дату на самом уведомлении.

Чтобы отобразить уведомление не сразу, а с задержкой, надо вручную это сделать. Есть много способов это сделать, выбор которых зависит от задач.

Самый, наверное, простой в данном конкретном случае - `postDelayed()`:

```
button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   public void run() { /*ТУТ КОД ОТОБРАЖЕНИЯ УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ*/ }
}, 60000);
```

Однако, если задержка может быть большой и должна срабатывать в т.ч. при незапущенном приложении - надо что-то другое использовать. Какой-нибудь `AlarmManager` + `BroadcatReceiver` или `workmanager`.